# Close UIAlertView with press of Return key on external keyboard

Tags: ios, uialertview

I am showing a simple alert view like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"msg" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
```

Now, if the user has an **external (bluetooth) keyboard attached**, I want to close the alert dialog if the user types the Return key.

How do I accomplish that?

The challenge here is to learn of the press of any key on the keyboard. Once that's know, dismissing the dialog is trivial (with `[UIAlertView  dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:...]`).

I've tried to implement the `[UIViewController keyCommands` function, returning a handler for "\r", but that only works while my main view shows, not while the alert is showing.

You can view a sample project here: https://github.com/tempelmann/AlertViewReturnKeyDismissal

**Note: So far, the two posted solutions below do NOT work in general, but only if the alert is shown from within `viewDidLoad`. I need this to work when I show the alert past `viewDidLoad`, though.**

Comment: Can't you use `textFieldShouldReturn:`? Isn't that called when an external keyboard hits return?

Comment: Globaly declare UIAlertView object, then dismis.

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets - the method you mention is for Text fields, and only for those that are having focus. There is no such view in a UIAlertView as far as I can see. So how do you imagine this to work?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: Ah, I see. I thought your alert actually had an text field, but you want to dismiss an alert that does not have a text field.

Comment: Could you use a Notification if user press return? Maybe on a second thread? Since UIAlertView seems to be blocking a few things on the thread...

Comment: @Larme I know of no notifications that get sent for key presses. Do you?

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me...

First set the view controller that is handling the alert view to the first responder with:

```
[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

Next be sure to override the following methods on your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

-(NSArray *)keyCommands {
    return @[[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"\r" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(enterPressed)]];
}
```

Then after displaying your alert view, since the view controller will still be the first responder, you can simply have your `enterPressed` method dismiss the alert view:

```
-(void)enterPressed {
    [self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Odd, I thought I had tried exactly what you suggest. I'll have to double check.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I have a view controller into which I put all the above functions, and which is also the delegate for the UIAlertView. Then I create and show the alert, but when I then press the Return key, nothing gets invoked. Am I on the wrong view controller? Does the Alert have its own? How do I get to it?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: The alert does have its own view controller. "Getting to it" is not something you want to do. The `keyCommands` method is called on the first responder. When your alert is shown, your view controller is normally not the first responder. However, you may be able to set yourself as the first responder after you show the alert (in `didPresentAlertView:`). Then Kevin's option may work for you.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann does the event fire correctly if the alert view is not shown?  The following worked for me, do you have a small test proj that demonstrates the above not working?

Comment: @ScottBerrevoets I had already tried what you suggest, i.e. calling `[self becomeFirstResponder];` in the alert's `didPresentAlertView:` callback. Not helping, either.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia. Yes, keyCommands works as long as the alert is not shown. Have you actually tried what you suggest and know that it works, or did you just guess the solution?

Comment: Note: I have just added the prj to github. See my question.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann Hmm it seems you are right, showing the alert outside of viewDidLoad never seems to call any of the key commands.  I did find this giant hack http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/adding-keyboard-shortcuts-to-uialertview/ but I'll keep digging to see if I can't find something better.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Peter Steinberger's post suggests that this issue is common and not solvable cleanly. Oh dear...

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann As another solution you could ditch the UIAlertView all together and write your own similar looking modal view, then this wouldn't be an issue, you'd just have to re-implement the niceties of the UIAlertView.

Answer (score 0):

I delete my last answer as UIAlertView wasn't firstResponder and it was a bad idea to make it firstResponder (side effects?).

So the trick is to create a custom view and to add it as firstResponder when alertView shows.

I put the code in a [github repo](https://github.com/Francescu/iOSShortscutAlertView/).

From the [ViewController](https://github.com/Francescu/iOSShortscutAlertView/blob/master/ShortcutAlertView/ViewController.m):

```
- (void)didPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
{
    [self.keyCommandsView becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self.keyCommandsView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

The [KeyCommandsView](https://github.com/Francescu/iOSShortscutAlertView/blob/master/ShortcutAlertView/KeyCommandsView.m) itself :

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSArray *)keyCommands {
    return @[[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"\r" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(enterPressed)]];
}

- (void)enterPressed
{
    [self.alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
```

I think the solution could be optimized by extending directly `UIResponder`, doing a singleton and adding a custom constructor method in UIAlertView category to perform the stuff automaticly.

Comment: This is jsut a working solution of course you have to adapt it to your project. The dimissWithClickedButtonIndex should be filled with `cancelButtonIndex`.

Comment: You're taking a shortcut that makes it work, oddly, but it's not right: Your code only works when the alert is shown from viewDidLoad. But as soon as you move it to viewDidAppear, it doesn't any more. If I show the alert in *my* code inside viewDidAppear, it works as well. So, we're back to square one.

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann interesting, I wonder if that's why it also worked for me.  I'm pretty sure I was just showing the alert in viewDidLoad as well.  I'll look into this more when I get home tonight.

Comment: Really strange I'm curious to know why it doesn't work after viewDidAppear.

Answer (score -1):

Declare the alertView globally.

and use

**[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];**

Comment: You have not understood the question.